# Download button not responding to ng-disabled in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have a webpage which displays contents of a folder/directory upon clicking on it. If the contents of a folder has files, then download button is activated. If the contents of the folder is a directory, download button is inactive.

Here is my code that is supposed to make that work. But the Download button remains active all the time and never goes inactive. Can somebody point out where I'm going wrong ?

```js
$scope.IsFile = function(filenames){
  forEach(filenames, function(filename){
   if(filename.indexOf(".zip") > 1|| filename.indexOf(".txt") >1 || filename.indexOf(".xml") > 1 ) {
    return true;
   }
   else {
    return false;
   }
  });
 };
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3" id="CTP Jobs">
  <div ng-click="GetListOfFilesonCTP('/home/topas/rda_app/JOBS/')">
   <a href="">
    <h3>
     JOBS <small> <span class="btn-group"
      role="group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="IsFile(listOfFilesOnJobs)"
        ng-click="download()">Download</button>
     </span>
     </small>
    </h3>
   </a>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped"
   ng-init="GetListOfFilesonCTP('/home/topas/rda_app/JOBS')">
   <tr ng-repeat="jobs in listOfFilesOnJobs"
    ng-click="GetListOfFilesonCTP(getPath('/home/topas/rda_app/JOBS/', jobs))">
    <!--'/home/topas/rda_app/JOBS/'+ jobs + '/'  -->
    <td><a href="">{{jobs}}</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IsFile` function does not return anything explicitly (i.e. it returns `undefined`) and `ng-disabled` interprets that as `false`. The `return true` and `return false` on lines 4 and 7 are relative to the function passed to `forEach`, which is probably not what you want. Did you mean to filter the list of files and check if any files are remaining? Something like this would do:

```
$scope.isFile = function(filenames) {
    return filenames.filter(function(filename) {
        return filename.indexOf(".zip") > 1 || 
            filename.indexOf(".txt") > 1 || 
            filename.indexOf(".xml") > 1
    }).length > 0
}
```

Comment: I want to check the content of the folder , ie array/list of contents in that  folder , and if there are any files ending with .zip, .xml or .txt, I want to return true.. If not, then return false.

I tried your code, but it didn't seem to work for my case..

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't seem to work"? The button is not in the state you want it to be? Could you give an example?

Comment: I'm new to angularjs.. I'm not aware of usage of filters.. I meant to say that the button does not get disabled at all. always remains enabled..

Comment: Be aware I'm not using a Angular.js filter here, only the vanilla JS [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. Here is a example of the solution working: https://jsfiddle.net/7jj0fcs6/.